# Australia Resident Return Visa (155 and 157)

Tags: visa, australia, residency

I am a permanent resident of Australia and my PR status is going to expire in mid of June, 2020. I had been to Australia and stayed for 2 weeks in November 2015. I'm currently living outside Australia due to work. My wife and daughter are also PR and they have already moved to Australia in January 2020.

Questions:
1. Do I need apply for RRV before my PR expires? If not, can I apply for RRV on February 2021?
2. If I apply now and receive (hopefully) RRV for 1 year/3 months, does this period starts from the expiry date of my current PR?
3. If I receive the RRV (hopefully) and cannot move to Australia for some reason, will I be able to apply for RRV again?

Thanks in advance for your kind response.

Comment: Questions about long term migration, including permanent residence, belong on [expatriates.se]

Comment: Just to clarify, permanent residence does not expire. What does expire is the right to reenter Australia.

Comment: @jcm, since I’m living outside Australia, will I be able to enter into Australia anytime in the future?

Comment: That's what the RRV is for. What I meant was if a permanent resident never leaves Australia they don't need an RRV or anything else to stay.

Comment: Thanks @jcm. I heard if I have not visited Australia in the past 5 years, I won't be able to apply for RRV. I have visited Australia on November 2015 which will become 5 years in November this year. So, will I be able to apply for RRV in June 2021?